# Capture network requests in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension, and I'm currently trying to capture all the fonts from a network request, and print their details to the console.

Here's what my background script looks like:

```
function processRequest(dict) {
  console.log("inside test");
  console.log(dict);
}

chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(processRequest, {
  urls: ["https://developer.chrome.com/*"],
  types: ["font"],
});

console.log("outside test");
```

When I look in the console, it prints `outside test` but not `inside test`. However, based on the [google's documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#type-RequestFilter) I would expect the code inside of my `processRequest` function to run.

Is there something that I'm missing here? My  goal is to capture all the fonts from the network request and print those to the console. Any help would be appreciated — thanks!

Comment: This code works for me, so I guess the problem is elsewhere. What's your `host_permissions` (MV3) or `permissions` (MV2)?

Comment: Yep you're right, it was a problem with the host permissions. Everything works now — thanks!